# Coda2 - Can't remove GitHub URL from settings

Tags: git, repository, coda

I messed up on my initial creation of my github.com repository in Coda2...  Now everytime I try to create a new site, Coda2 has my settings for the old repository in there and it won't let me change it...

Things I've tried:

1. Uninstall/reinstall
2. Locate all ".git" directories on machine and remove them
3. Delete all git repositories from github

None of these solutions are removing the url...  Anyone have any other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: what does `git config -l` say?

Comment: Macintosh:~ localuser$ git config -l
    filter.media.required=true
    filter.media.clean=git media clean %f
    filter.media.smudge=git media smudge %f
user.name=[MYGITUSER]